# Jade Template Event Handling

Tags: javascript, html, templates, pug

I'm new to a lot of javascript and definitely new to Jade templates.  I have figured out how to render a small form (textbox and a button) with a template and I have compiled the javascript file to use on the client.  I have been able to read that html template up and put into a div in a consuming web page and it shows correctly.

```
{
html = template()
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=html;
}
```

Here's what I can't figure out:

I want other areas of the consuming web page to be able to subscribe to click events on that button.  I'm not clear at all how I can have some kind of event notification on this button so when it is clicked, the listeners will be notified of what was typed in the box when the button was clicked.

At the consuming web page level, I guess I could run some kind of event listener and have subscribers listen and be notified at that level.  However, I'd like to be able to look at this as a 'component' and subscribe to events directly on what the template produces...

Long story short, is there any way to add functions like 'addListener' to this button in the template?  Since the template just produces a string of html rather than an object I'm a bit at a loss as to how I might do this.

Am I trying to do something that is beyond the scope of templates?  What should I be using that will separate my code into a 'component' that can be rendered in it's own page or loaded into a consuming web page, and have events subscribed to?

Thanks for any guidance.

---EDIT---
Here is some code that might show more about what I'm trying to accomplish.  This does not work, as expected... I hope it illustrates what I'm after though.  Essentially I want the produced code from the template to be an object that I can subscribe to events.  I don't think it's possible, but if someone could guide me in another direction that would be great! Thanks

**main.html -- shows how I'd like to add listeners to a component**

```
{
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Main Content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jade.js"></script>
  <script src="search.js"></script>
  <script src="runtime.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
      html = search()
      alert(html)
      document.getElementById('left').innerHTML = html
    });

    searchListener = function(searchText){
      alert(searchText);
    }
    addSearchListener(searchListener);

  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-sm-4">

    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-sm-8">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
}
```

**search.html (produced from jade template)**

```
{
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="search.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var listeners = [];

      function search(){
        var searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        notifySearchListeners(searchText);
      }

      function addSearchListener(listener){
        listeners.push(listener)
      }

      function notifySearchListeners(searchText){
        for (i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
          listener = listeners[i];
          listener(searchText);
        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="search">
      <h3>Search</h3>
      <input type="text" id="searchText">
      <button onClick="search()">Search</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to write javascript in the template? If so you can write it just like you would write a script withing a script tag in HTML.

Comment: I have added an edit and some example (wrong) code that might illustrate what I'm trying to do.  I figure that I'm trying to do more than the template should be used for, but am unclear as to how I should go about doing it.  Any guidance appreciated!